# Validate URL information in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate the output that the below script generates. The information is being parsed through a proxy which has all the information encoded correctly (for example & being &) however when I use the W3 Validator I get the following

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been
>   escaped as &.)
>   …://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgALxO5r7_0&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
>   class="wa…

I have tried but to no success to figure out what is going wrong between the proxy and the output. Any help would be appreciated. I think the issue is around

> src: escape( $(this).find('link').text()),

Full Source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    projekktor('#player_a', {
    useYTIframeAPI: false,
    width: 730,
    height: 452,
    plugin_display: {
        logoImage: "includes/images/transIcon.png"
    },
    controls: true,
    playlist: [{0:{src:'includes/proxy.php?url=http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/SkiBsandDXL/uploads?alt=rss&amp;v=2&amp;orderby=published', type:"text/xml"}}],
    reelParser: function(xmlDocument) {
        var result = {};
        var regMatch = new RegExp("http:[^ ,]+\.jpg");  
        result['playlist'] = [];
        $(xmlDocument).find("item").each(function() {
        try {
            result['playlist'].push({
            0:{
                src: escape( $(this).find('link').text()),          
                type: 'video/youtube'
            },
            config: {
                poster: regMatch.exec(unescape( $(this).find('description').text())),
                title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                desc: $(this).find('description').text()
            }
            });
        } catch(e){}
        });
        return result;
    } 
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a few wild guesses here:

Guess one is that you are using an `XHTML doctype`.  Unless you know how exactly how `XHTML` differs from `HTML` then use `HTML`.  `HTML 4.01 strict` or `HTML5`.

Again, working on my guess that your working with `XHTML`, the contents of your script element need to be `CDATA`. This is reason enough to not use `XHTML`.

If you must use XHTML, then either put in the CDATA wrapper, or make your script external.  Having the scripts external is always a good idea anyways.